# Need to create custom classpath.idx for springboot app to control jar loading order

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I've discovered a situation where a SpringBoot service is using two maven dependencies that mostly deal with different things, but which happen to have at least one fully-qualified class name that is in both artifacts.  This service is failing at startup because it ends up using the class from one jar, where it really needs to get it from the other jar.

I have another service that has the same two dependencies, but does not have this problem. but I see that in the fat jar, the order of the two jars is different from the one that has the problem.

There's no question that this is a stupid situation.  One of those jars should absolutely not have that class (and other classes in the same package), but I don't have any control over that artifact, and it's a legacy artifact.

From what I understand, problems like this are dealt with using a custom "classpath.idx" file.  It's possible I can get away with that file just having two entries in it, the two jars that I need to control the ordering for.

What I don't understand is how to get it there.  I assume that if I put the file in src/main/resources, that will dump it into BOOT-INF/classes, but it needs to go into BOOT-INF.

I would have thought functionality around this would have been available in the spring-boot-maven-plugin, but I don't see anything. Perhaps it's so simple to do this that it wasn't deemed necessary.  If so, I don't see how to do it.

I also wondered whether simply changing the order of dependencies in the maven pom.xml could do this, but I've tried moving the artifact that references this problem artifact as a transient dependency to both first and last in the dependences list, but that made no difference.